# Request method as parameter in function not working properly

Tags: shell, curl, jq

Here is a function that executes a GET request for a given URL

```
mycurl() {
curl -X GET \
     -H 'Accept: application/vnd.layer+json; version=3.0' \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer qFyBLjM9mhOlIwjZCeblbV9CrLZh2rqNzVIlIuf8a07UBj5F' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    "$@"}

exportsData=$(mycurl https://api.layer.com/apps/9d649224-cde5-11e7-b916-f3d1a15f96fe/exports)
count=$(jq -r '.|length' <<<"$exportsData")
echo $count;
```

This prints the count once as :

30

I am trying to convert the mycurl function to accept request method as a parameter like so

```
mycurl() {
curl -X "$@" \
     -H 'Accept: application/vnd.layer+json; version=3.0' \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer qFyBLjM9mhOlIwjZCeblbV9CrLZh2rqNzVIlIuf8a07UBj5F' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    "$@"}
exportsData=$(mycurl GET https://api.layer.com/apps/9d649224-cde5-11e7-b916-f3d1a15f96fe/exports)
count=$(jq -r '.|length' <<<"$exportsData")
echo $count;
```

The output of the above is

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
100 52280  100 52280    0     0  39425      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 10742
30 30
```

What’s the issue? Why is count being printed twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your first argument from the rest of arguments in your function `mycurl()`. Do a capture of `$1` and use the `shift` once to pass the rest of the arguments as below

```
mycurl() {
    reqMethod=$1; shift

    curl -X "$reqMethod" \
         -H 'Accept: application/vnd.layer+json; version=3.0' \
         -H 'Authorization: Bearer qFyBLjM9mhOlIwjZCeblbV9CrLZh2rqNzVIlIuf8a07UBj5F' \
         -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         "$@"
}
```

The reason being `$@` represents all the positional arguments passed to the function script, if you pass it to the `-X` it would be incorrect. So we store the first argument in a variable and the `shift` call will now hold rest of the arguments except `$1` which then can be passed to the acutal `curl`.

Also if you are exactly sure of only two arguments to the script, just `$1` for request method and `$2` for the URL to be passed.